# Vector Resolution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vectors

I want to clarify if this statement

> $F_3$ is resolved along the u and w axes

means that the $F_3$ is sort of a resultant of u and w axes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By resolving it's doesn't mean that it's sort of resultant of $u$ and  $w$ because $uw$ are used as axis. You should say one can write $\mathbf{F}$ as linear combination of component along $u$ and $w$ so  that
$$\mathbf{F}=F_u\hat{u}+F_w\hat{w}$$
where $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{w}$ are unit vector along these axis.

Comment: In a sense, aren't resolving and finding the resultant actually opposite operations?

Comment: Yes! But if there are many forces are acting in a random direction then it's helpful to first resolve them in a certain direction (x and y), add these components, and then write (or draw) the resultant.